# Using UIRefreshControl in UIViewController with UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I wonder how i can use UIRefreshController for a UITableView inside a UIViewController.

I want to implement pull-to-refresh functionality to TableView but i don't have a TableViewController.

Is there a way to do this in xcode 6 (swift)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course you can do this. Initiate a RefreshControl and simply put it as subview of your tableview. You don't necessarily  need a `UITableViewController` for this.

EDIT:

Try something like this:

```
let control = UIRefreshControl()
control.addTarget(self, action: "action", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
tableView.addSubview(control)
```

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Objective-C version that worked for me in case anyone needs it. I added it to `viewDidLoad`:

```
UIRefreshControl *refresh = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[refresh addTarget: self action: @selector(didPullToRefresh:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.tableView addSubview: refresh];
```

Not a fan of `UITableViewController`...